# Collecting the data into one object and sorting it in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

In our .NET/C# project we save all the users' browser name/version, OS name, etc. in the database. Later on we grab that data and use for statistics purposes. Now I need to somehow define, for example:

5 customers had Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 8
4 customers had Windows XP + Internet Explorer 6
etc.

When getting the data from the database, I can define which OS and which browser was used, but the case is that when I collect the data, how would I get which browser and which OS were used together and get the quantity of such platforms? For example I would search Windows XP and the system would show me which browsers were used with that OS and in what quantity.

Could anybody give a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect fit for the `GROUP BY` operator (if you're using SQL), or the Linq `GroupBy()` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) if you're wanting to stay within .NET.

For example, in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), OS, BROWSER
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY OS, BROWSER
```

Or, in Linq:

```
var groups = from yt in yourtable
             group yt by new { yt.OS, yt.BROWSER } into ytgroup
             select new { key = ytgroup.key, groups = ytgroup };
```

From here, you'll have a set of groups, from which you can then obtain the counts.

Comment: Can't use GROUP BY for SQL, don't have a right to alter the stored procedure. Will take a look at LINQ's GrouBy() though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at grouping. In linq that might look something like:

```
var info = from record in records where record.OperatingSystem == "WinXp"
    group record by record.Browser into g
    select new { Browser = g.Key, Records = g };
```

If you use something like ravendb you will have a very nice way of doing this without the complicated impedance missmatch that SQL RDBMS inherantly brings. Meaning you can query it directly with this linq.

hth

Comment: I think you mean "impedance" mismatch, but "impotence" made me chuckle. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Create `Dictionary<string, int> d;`

Let your key be strings such as 'Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 8' or 'Windows XP + Internet Explorer 6'.  You will probably have your key generation routine ready.

Do this:

```
foreach (CollectedDataItem item in CollectedData)
{
    string key=generateKeyFromItem(item);
    if (!d.HasKey(key)) {
         d.Add(key, 1);
    }
    else {
         d[key]++;
    }
}
```

And finally,

```
string generateKeyFromItem(CollectedDataItem Item)
{
    return Item.OS+" "+Item.Browser;
}
```

Comment: "Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 8" and "Windows XP + Internet Explorer 6" were just examples. In reality there would be too many keys if I did so - Windwos XP + FireFox + Java 1.6 + .NET3.5 etc + Flash 10, etc.

Comment: @cycero: But, why is that a problem? Daniel's solution can handle any arbitrary number of combinations.

Comment: generate you keys as distinctly or as broadly as you need.  it's up to you.  or, rewrite your question - because maybe you need completely different set of results...